# IBM Worklight 6.0 - Blackberry WebWorks JavaScript extension on BlackBerry 10

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, blackberry-10, blackberry-webworks

I am using IBM worklight 6 on eclipse and am interested in devleoping for Blackberry 10 (WebWorks).

1. Can I use JavaScript extension in a BlackBerry 10 WebWorks-based application?
2. If yes, what changes do I need to make it compatible with BlackBerry 10?

Any link related to this issue will be highly appreciated.

Comment: "javascript extension"?

Comment: Is this question resolved?

Answer (score 0):

Nothing special from the Worklight side of things.
Follow BlackBerry's guidelines: http://developer.blackberry.com/html5/

If this doesn't answer your question, then ask a specific question.